# How to fix ajax that loads a class on a page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a comment column by putting `process.php` in the page header, but when I want to load a `#comment-list`, 1 page entered into the div.

I've tried changing `ajax.url` and it works, but it will affect the entire system that was created.

I want to load this part when ajax is successful

**HTML**

```
    <div id="comment-list" class="widget-body">
      <?php news_comment($server_conn,$id_news); ?>
    </div>
```

**FORM**

```
      <form action="<?php echo FullURL() ?>" method="post" id="newcomment">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">* Comment:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="text_comment" placeholder="Your Comment" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-comment" name="submit-comment" value="<?php echo $row['id_news']; ?>">Post Comment</button>
        </form>
```

**AJAX**

```
        $("#submit-comment").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var submit = $(this).attr('value');
            var post_url = $("#newcomment").attr("action");
            var request_method = $("#newcomment").attr("method");
            var form_data = $("#newcomment").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url : post_url,
                type: request_method,
                data : form_data + '&submit-comment=' + submit,
                success: function(){
                    $("#newcomment")[0].reset();
                    $("#comment-list").load(post_url + "#comment-list");
                }
            })
        });
```

When Ajax responds successfully, I want `#comment-list` loads automatically, without entering a 1-page display

Comment: Try `$("#comment-list").load(post_url + " #comment-list");` (note the space before ` #comment-list`).   See https://api.jquery.com/load/ "Loading Page Fragments"

Comment: can you put news_comment html in your answer?

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks man, problem solved

Comment: You need a space before the selector in `load()`, *however* it would be far better practice, and place less load on your server, if you just returned the HTML from the original AJAX request.